# How to create a Dataflow Template without running code?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am creating a Dataflow template that runs perfectly if I pass all required parameters but my use case is to create a Generic Template where I can pass parameters at Runtime.

All my options are ValueProvider but still, it is trying to execute the code while creating the template and that gives an error. Is there any way I can create a Dataflow template without executing code?

I have also faced one weird issue when I use create template command along with all the parameters then it creates the template successfully but at that time all parameters get hard coded in the code and if I pass the new parameter value while running it does not change the value with the template.

Is it the correct behavior of the Dataflow template?

Command without passing all parameters :

```
mvn compile exec:java  -D"exec.mainClass"="org.example.Main" -D"exec.args"="--runner=DataflowRunner --project=<project>  --stagingLocation=gs://test-bucket/staging_4 --templateLocation=gs://test-bucket/templates/my_template  --region=asia-south1 "  -P dataflow-runner -X
```

Comment: It has to run the code to create the Pipeline/graph. You mean it is executing the pipeline where it shouldn't?

Comment: it is not actually executing the code (such as moving data) but I am facing one issue with it. If I does not pass parameter then it give compile time error and if I pass then it create template but does not allow to change the value while I create a job with that template.

Comment: @BrunoVolpato my major concern is when I use this template in Dataflow Job, it does not overwrite the parameter value that I am passing through Dataflow UI (with a custom template) and it keeps the value of the same parameter that I have used while creating template.

Comment: I'd suggest updating the question with as many details as possible.  I for one switched to using Dataflow Flex templates and have had good luck with those.

Comment: Hi @NikhilSuthar, can you provide the sample code and clarify your requirement?

Comment: I have done changes in the code and now I am able to create a template, we can close this.

Comment: It will be great if you can add an answer explaining what was wrong so others that get into the same situation can also get unblocked! Thanks Nikhil.

Comment: Hi @NikhilSuthar, can you post your answer so that it will help the community in their research also?

Answer (score 1):

After designing my code multiple times,  I got to know what mistake I was doing.

What I got to know is that your code should be designed in such a way that it will not ask for any value for generating the Graph except Project Id, Stage Path, and Template Path. if it is asking then check the below practices and design accordingly.

Following are the practice you should follow if you are creating Custom Template.

**1**.Declare all the options as `ValueProvider` so that it will be calculated at Run Time and the Template creation process will skip it.

**2**.Do not assign the ValueProvider value to the normal variable as below.

```
String Query = options.getQuery().toString();
PCollection<TableRow> rows = p.apply("Read From Source", JdbcIO.<TableRow>read()
              .withQuery(Query)
```

**3**.Try to pass `ValueProvider` value directly to the method. For example above code snippet should be like below

```
PCollection<TableRow> rows = p.apply("Read From Source", JdbcIO.<TableRow>read()
              .withQuery(options.getQuery())
```

**4**.Do not use options only inside any one particular block of code which is never accessible during Template creation. As below example.

```
Boolean Check = false;

if (options.getA().isAccessible()){
   Check = true;
}   
if (Check == true){
  //Use of Options.getB().
}
```

In the above case if you are not pass `--a` option while creating a template then the `Check` value will always `false` and a particular below block of code will not be executable. If we are not using `--b` out of `Check` block then after the creation of Template options `b` will be unknown to Template and it will give an error if you pass it at Run time.

**5**.If you have use case where you need to manipulate data of input options passed then you should use `NestedValueProvider` instead of converting `ValueProvider` into a Normal variable such as String and manipulate data.

Fo example, avoid the below practice.

```
String Query = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s", options.getTableName().toString());
PCollection<TableRow> rows = p.apply("Read From Source", JdbcIO.<TableRow>read()
                  .withQuery(Query)
```

Instead implement same logic as below:

```
ValueProvider<String> Query = NestedValueProvider.of(options.getTableName(),
                                new SerializableFunction<String, String>() {
                                @Override
                             public String apply(TranslatorInput<String, String> input) 
                              {
                                return String.format("SELECT * FROM %s", input);;
                             }
                            });;
PCollection<TableRow> rows = p.apply("Read From Source", JdbcIO.<TableRow>read()
                  .withQuery(Query)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [FlexTemplates](https://dataintegration.info/why-you-should-be-using-flex-templates-for-your-dataflow-deployments) instead. Documentation can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates).